# How do I connect to a server using IPv6 in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, networking

My Internet connection doesn't have its own dedicated IPv4 address. I've port forwarded my Ubuntu computer to the DMZ, which I know is working because I have Apache installed and the web server is accessible from the IPv6 address.

When I put in an IPv6 address into Minecraft, it doesn't seem to work. How do you connect using IPv6 in Minecraft? Is there something special you need to do?

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way to do this in unmodded (vanilla) Minecraft. I'd suggest buying a domain and using something like Dreamhost DNS to route the domain or a subdomain to the IP.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in modded Minecraft?

Comment: You can do pretty much anything with modded Minecraft. I'm not familiar enough with Java to tell you how to do it though.

Answer (score 2):

Use the raw IPv6 address without the brackets (example: `::1`) and it should work.

I have been using this technique on Minecraft 1.8.9 and 1.15.2 for one year to connect to Minecraft servers that expose an IPv6 address into their DNS records.

Answer (score 2):

- Both `IPv6` and `[IPv6]:port` formats should work when entering IP addresses
- If you share from a local network, make sure you share the correct address (the machine should have a public IPv6 address. Do not take the Router's one). Good router UIs will tell you which one to use
- If you have a domain/DNS entry, this will probably not work because Minecraft only tries connecting to its IPv4 address. Starting the client with `-Djava.net.preferIPV4stack=false` might help
- If you set the DNS record to your local network using something like DynDNS, don't forget that the IP should point to your machine and not the router. So you either need to run a DynDNS client on your server, or some routers support providing custom IP addresses through scripts for this use case (OpenWRT for example).